# C Dynamic Array of Struct in [Array of Struct in [Array of Struct in [Array of Struct ]]]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I want to store a 100 employees. RollNo,Name,Salary,and the time(various data, I'm unable to explain here but you can understand be seeing below code snippet

```
main() 
{
    struct day {
      int hour[40];
      int min[40];
      int mins[40];
      int rec;
      int totmins;
      int totsal;
      char status;
      int temp;
    };
    struct month {
      struct day * da[31];
    };

    struct year {
      struct month * mn[12];
    };

    struct roll {
      int rn;
      char name[30];
      int salary;
      struct year * yr[25];
    };
```

so I dynamically allocated the memory by

```
struct day *da[31];
    for(i=0;i<=31;i++)
        {   da[i]=(struct day*)malloc(31 * sizeof *da);
             if( da[i]== NULL )
             {printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for day\n",i);getch();exit(0);}
        }

struct month *mn[12];
    for(i=0;i<=12;i++)
        {   mn[i]=(struct month*)malloc( 12 * sizeof *mn);
            if( mn[i]== NULL )
             {printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for month\n",i);getch();exit(0);}
        }

struct year *yr[25];
    for(i=0;i<=25;i++)
        {   yr[i]=(struct year*)malloc( 25 * sizeof *yr);
            if( yr[i]== NULL )
                {printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for year\n",i);getch();exit(0);}
        }

struct roll *rol[100];
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {   rol[i]=(struct roll*)malloc(100 * sizeof *rol));
             if( rol[i]== NULL )
             {printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for roll\n",i);getch();exit(0);}
        }
```

But in my actual piece of code, when i do 
[consider d=27,m=1,y=15 and i=1]

```
rol[i] - > yr[y] - > mn[m] - > da[d] - > rec++;
```

it is incrementing remaining members also, that is

```
rol[2] - > yr[y] - > mn[m] - > da[d] - > rec++;
.
.

rol[100] - > yr[y] - > mn[m] - > da[d] - > rec++;
```

Which means there is some error in the allocation only...Could anyone help me out?

---

MODIFIED CODE:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      rol[i] = (struct roll * ) malloc(100 * sizeof(struct roll));
      if (rol[i] == NULL) {
        printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for roll\n", i);
        getch();
        exit(0);
      }
      for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        rol[i] -> yr[j] = (struct year * ) malloc(25 * sizeof(struct year));
        if (rol[i] -> yr[j] == NULL) {
          printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for year\n", i);
          getch();
          exit(0);
        }

        for (k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
          rol[i] -> yr[j] -> mn[k] = (struct month * ) malloc(12 * sizeof(struct month));
          if (rol[i] -> yr[j] -> mn[k] == NULL) {
            printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for month\n", i);
            getch();
            exit(0);
          }

          for (l = 0; l < 31; l++) {
            rol[i] -> yr[j] -> mn[k] -> da[l] = (struct day * ) malloc(31 * sizeof(struct day));
            if (rol[i] -> yr[j] -> mn[k] -> da[l] == NULL) {
              printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for day\n", l);
              getch();
              exit(0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

but I'm getting that it couldn't allocate memory...

Comment: Your `malloc`s appear to be wrong, what are you trying to allocate for? and did you know about `free()`? also, I don't think you need `malloc()` in this case, you can use arrays instead.

Comment: <31, not <=31.  Learn to declare constants instead of having [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) all over the place.   why do the sub-structs even need to be dynamic?

Comment: You might want to include more relevant code; the code as is probably cannot exhibit the described problem. Ideally, make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the malloc calls are all allocating pointer sized items rather than struct sized items.  suggest removing the '*' after the 'sizeof' in each malloc call

Comment: You never allocate memory for `yr->mn` or `yr->mn->da` etc.  (The other `mn` allocations are a separate variable called `mn`).  This whole idea is terrible and you should fix it by not using pointers and not using malloc.

Comment: kARTechnology, do you intend to replace your old code by other code that exhibits another unrelated problem? If yes, please ask a different question. If no, please leave only one code snippet, which is relevant to your original problem.

Comment: @anatolyg I have inserted the modified code, which is simply a revision as said by user324903...so you want me to create a new question and flood stackoverflow with my questions, each time after revising? I'm new here. the whole point of the question is to build a large structure in a large structure successfully.

Comment: @kARTechnology In order to get useful answers, you should describe exactly (as much as you can) what problem you are trying to solve. If you change your question after one problem was solved (not sure you did it; just guessing), people who try to answer will be confused, which will make life harder for *you*. Regarding flooding: you are supposed to try solving your problem before posting each question. If you are stuck, ask a question (only after you tried to solve the problem by yourself). In this situation, your questions will be *good*, and the more *good* questions, the better.

Comment: @kARTechnology Also, numerous people, including user324903, suggested simplifying your allocations. I think you should write, in your question, why you want to do the allocations the way you did them (which is complicated, leading to bugs), or, alternatively, change them (and accept the answer if it helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anywhere that you initialize any pointers. Maybe the pointer initialization is in code you did not reveal.

malloc() returns uninitialized memory. The debug option of the compiler probably initializes memory returned from malloc(). The initialization would be to some value or values other than zero that likely would aid in debugging. For example, the The debug version of malloc() might allocate the requested amount plus 5 bytes. The officially allocated amount might be initialized to 0xa5a and the extra 5 bytes might be initialized to 0x5a5. That way, a small overrun of a buffer (overruns of less than 5 bytes) can usually be detected.

I think your code shows calling malloc() 32 + 13 + 26 + 101 = 172 times. But I suspect that you want to call malloc() 31 * 12 * 25 * 100 = 230,000 times. That is a lot of allocations and a whole lot of memory. But looks like that is what you intended. You want 31 days and therefore 31 allocations for each month. You want 12 months for each year, 25 years for each rn, and 100 rns. So, that looks to me more like a multiplication instead of an addition of malloc() calls.

I am guessing that you have not initialized your pointers and are using a debugging version of malloc(). Your uninitialized pointers are the 101 * 26 = 2626 year pointers. That is 25 pointers for each of your 101 rns. Then for each year pointer, you have 13 month pointers that are uninitialized, etc.

What I suppose is happening in your code is the processor is using the debug initialization of malloc memory as an address to reference. If memory were initialized to zero-bytes, the processor would detect a NULL pointer and you would get a runtime error. However, the processor thinks that you are referencing by a valid address, therefore does not complain. What comes out is that you are incrementing some wild address that has nothing to do with your structures. Because all of your structures are using the same wild address, it appears as if all recs are being incremented.

What you need to do is allocate for rn. Then for each rn, allocate for each of the 25 years. Make sure each year of the rn POINTS TO an allocation for the year. That is the initialization. Then for each rn and each year, allocate for the month, and initialize so each month points to an allocation....etc.

Sounds like a lot of work, and complicated. Therefore, if you have a choice, you might want to dream up some other solution.

To come up with another solution, you could think how you would lay out your fields (columns) in Excel. And that would get you down to one struct. You could probably call malloc() just one time (already much simpler).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct day *da[31];
    for(i=0;i<=31;i++)
        {   da[i]=(struct day*)malloc(31 * sizeof *da);
             if( da[i]== NULL )
             {printf("%d Couldn't able to allocate requested memory for day\n",i);getch();exit(0);}
        }
```

This code is wrong.

You are creating an array of structs with 31 elements. 0-30.

You in the loop are going through 32 elements or 0-31.

Change <=31 to <31